# How to changing action in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Currently my character having this to make action:

```
SKAction* action1 = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:textureArray timePerFrame:0.2]];
[_character runAction:action1];
```

then during the game, at a condition, I need to change the character's texture as well as his action:

```
  SKAction* action2 = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:textureArray2 timePerFrame:0.2]];
        SKAction* changeTexture2 = [SKAction setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"newtexture"]];
        [_character runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[changeTexture2,action2]]];
```

I can see the character with the old textture and action 1, then at condition satisfied, he changed texture, but no action shows.
I tried remove first action, and many different change but I can not get he change both appearance and action. I really don't know how they change the action in the game? I tried to google but I can't really find any right place ...
Thank you!

Comment: How it's possible to animate a `SKSpriteNode` with textures and set it's texture at same time?

Comment: Yes, it looks like I can do that normally if I do not need to change its textures after that. The texture is getting from one of the textures in the set to create animation.

Comment: Try using [_character removeAllActions] before setting action2 and changetexture2

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't effect.

Comment: I really don't know how they change the action in normal game ? Google didn't help much ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this changes:

```
  SKAction *action1 = ...
  [_character runAction:action1 withKey:@"action1"];
```

after:

```
  [_character removeActionForKey:@"action1"];
  [_character setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"newtexture"]];
  SKAction *action2 = [SKAction animateWithTextures:textureArray2 
                                       timePerFrame:0.2]];
  [_character runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:action2]];
```

Comment: Same result Bro, it changes the texture but not the action. There is no action after changing the texture.

Comment: @user1314404 are you sure that textureArray2 is not nil?

Comment: Yes, I checked with debug, it contains 3 objects (That is 3 objects to create the action, correct one) !

Comment: I really don't know how they change the action in normal game ?

Comment: @user1314404 try this code, but removing the line where texture changes

Comment: Tried it and the same thing happened. At first, have action1, then the texture still changed, but not the action!

Comment: @user1314404 this code works well.. is there any particular code after action2?

Comment: No there is not. What is the meaning of removeActionForKey? because later when the game stop at a condition, I see the action2 happen, at this point, I do use [self removeActionForKey:@"backgroundchange"]; and  [self runAction:[ ... withKey:@"backgroundchange"]; it bring back action2. But before that it doesnot appear.

Comment: in my code I give a key to action1 called "action1", this is useful in this case for remove that action and start another. removeActionForKey just serves to remove an action with a key.

Comment: Or is this causes because I put everything in (void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {} ? is this the right place that can make thing happens repeatedly?

Comment: oh no.. update is not the right position to put this code.. update is called every frame about 60 times for second.. try to put code in other method, update serves for other things

Comment: Yes! Perfect! That is where the problem lies. I put it to touchesBegan and it works! Thank you for your help !!